# Can I deploy Joomla on my desktop within the same FastStack service I implemented for SugarCRM (running Apache and MySql via FastStack)? If so how?

Tags: mysql, joomla, desktop, sugarcrm

The problem is that I am unable to get Joomla to create the Mysql database. It is saying that I may not have enough permissions to create a new database. I know how to create a database on a typical web host server, but not finding the same set up on the FastStack desktop implementation. Joomla wants me to make the database, but how do I do that? I suspect the Faststack is set-up only to support Sugar and is not expandable to add more databases. In which case, I would need to deploy a full version of Mysql on my desktop? And maybe a full version of Apache? Or maybe better to find a FastStack implementation of Joomla, as well?

How to do that, if so? THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

What mysql account are you using when you setup the mysql in the install app? If you use the root user you should have full permissions. You could also just use the database that is already there. All Joomla tables have a prefix of jos_ so should not cause conflict with sugar tables.